# Random library in python: .sample and .choices

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the `random` library there are .sample and .choices and I don't know what the differences are.

The documentation states that .sample has no replacement, but I don't know what exactly that means.

I tried using both but didn't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

example: a=[1,2,3]

random.choice(a) would return you a **number**, whichever in the list a

random.sample(a) would return an error, since it needs another param k, meaning how many samples you would like to get

random.sample(a, 1) would return a **list**, [1] or [2] or [3], here nothing to do with replacement

but if k=2, random.sample(a, 2) may give you [1,2] or [2,1] or [1,3] or [3,1] or [2,3] or [3,2]. it never gives you [1,1],[2,2] or [3,3] back, that means no replacement. when 1 has already been sampled firstly, 1 won't be sampled secondly.